# Как выбрать самые часто встречающиеся значения для каждого столбца таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Найти самое часто встречающееся значение *для одного столбца* можно при помощи запроса:

```
  SELECT foo
    FROM bar
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1;
```

Но как составить запрос, если нужно сделать выборку по всем полям таблицы, выбрав самые частотные значения для *каждого* столбца?

Comment: Без отдельных запросов, думаю никак. Организовать можно одним большим запросом через 'UNION', но фактически эти все равно разные запросы в базу...

Comment: Если отбросить в сторону вопросы производительности, то в БД где есть аналитические функции (MySql к ним не относится, к сожалению) можно было бы извратится как-то так, [например](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adfec1/21). А тут, видимо, действительно придется делать множество запросов.

Answer (score 3):

думаю поможет вот это,

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT foo1
    FROM bar
    GROUP BY foo1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , foo1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS foo1,

  ( SELECT foo2
    FROM bar
    GROUP BY foo2
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS foo2,
...
  ( SELECT fooN
    FROM bar
    GROUP BY fooN
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , fooN DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS fooN;
```

SQL-Fiddle: [test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97226/1)

Answer (score 0):

если сортировки не взаимосвязаны порядком применения (сначала сортировка по одному столбцу, затем по другому, и т.д.), то для каждого столбца придётся применять отдельный оператор `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
Боюсь оказаться не правым, но может быть так:

```
Select foo, Count(foo) as c
From bar
Group by foo
Having c > 5;
```

Comment: Боюсь оказаться не правым, но кажется вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы правы, поспешил.
Как и прокомментировал **cyadvert**, за один запрос никак.